# How to formulate an SQL-In-Query more efficiently?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL-query:

```
select x
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.x = t2.x
where t1.x in ( SUBQUERY )
```

The result of the subquery is fixed and independent of the rest of the query.

If I write the code for the subquery in there, it takes ages, even though the subquery evaluates rather fast. However, if I paste the result values of the subquery in there manually, the whole query evaluates fast again.
I assume this is because using the code instead of pasting it manually results in unnecessary multiple evaluations of the subquery.

How can I avoid those?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We would need to see the table definitions to be sure, but I'm guessing you don't have any indexes on the tables.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Luckily, x is a primary key in my table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) means

Comment: Are you *sure* that your subquery is not correlated to your main query someway (does it have `t1` or `t2` in it)?  Otherwise, it should perform as fast as one evaluation of the subquery plus the main query with the values explicitly stated between the parens.  Would be helpful to see the actual subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many Databases, if the result of the subquery which uses `in` statement is large, then your performance will be bad. And `not in` command gets very very bad performance. I recommended to you use joining tables. For Example:

```
-- not recommended
select * from test_table a1 
where id in (select id from test)

-- recommended
select * from test_table a1 
inner join test a2 on a1.id = a2.id
```

And instead of `NOT IN`:

```
-- not recommended
select * from test_table a1 
where id not in (select id from test)


-- recommended
select * from test_table a1 
left join test a2 on a1.id = a2.id 
where a2.id is null;
```